# C # - Mssql | The problem of connecting 2 computers on the same network to the database on the public network at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 2 computers. These computers are connected to the same network. The database file is in a folder on the public network. I can access the database at different times from the two computers. But at the same time, 2 computers cannot connect to the database.

Computer 1: Laptop - Name : HKTURAN

Computer 2: Desktop - Name : DESKTOP/H7JY5F

If I first log in with a laptop, I get this error on the desktop : Cannot open database “MyDatabase” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP/H7JY5F'

If I first log in with a desktop, I get this error on the laptop : Cannot open database “MyDatabase” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'HKTURAN'

Please Help Me... Thank You....

Database : MSSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the database file is in folder

This is the issue. You use database file. Let me explain you how it works. To open the db from your laptop, you connect to its file, it gets activated and some kind of a very stripped instance of MSSQL Express server is being run. This server launches and locks DB file. When you try connecting to the same file for the second time from another computer, another instance of MSSQL server is being run! But it cannot access and lock the db file, because it's already in use! I suggest using MSSQL Server instead of DB file. You can have multiple instances of applications connected to the same server, but not multiple servers connected to the same db.

Comment: My connection : public SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb ; AttachDbFileName= " + path + @"\" + databaseName + "; Integrated Security=True;USER ID=sa;PASSWORD=deneme");

I would appreciate if you give detailed information :(
Is this connection string issue?

Comment: Let me make it simple. You need A SERVER to access the same db from multiple apps. You can download one here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads . After downloading, you install it, import the db into that server and use SERVER CONNECTION STRING in both apps. Now you have NO SERVER. It means, you are accessing the file directly. It is perfect for storing some inner data or app settings for a single app. You cannot use the same db file in multiple apps at the same time.

Comment: Imagine your DB is a book. Only 1 person can read it at a time. So, for multiple persons to get info at the same time, you need someone to reed it out loud. The third person- a server.

Comment: Oh! I got it now! Thank you very much!